# python:Merging button yields "not defined"

Tags: python

I am trying to display B4 button inside the Application but it doesnot display inside it and yields me" B4 is not defined"

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()
B1 = tkinter.Button(top, text ="circle", relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="circle")
B2 = tkinter.Button(top, text ="plus", relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="plus")
B3 = tkinter.Button(top, text=u"good !",relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="plus")
def initialise(self):
    self.grid()                                
    B4 = tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click me !",                                                              
                                command=self.OnButtonClick)
    button.grid(column=1,row=0)
def OnButtonClick(self):
    print( "You clicked the button" )
B1.pack()
B2.pack()
B3.pack()
B4.pack()
initialise()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: You already asked this exact question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24028279/3651800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the scope of the function `initialize` does not extend to the main program. Therefore, `B4` is undefined.

Also, you are not passing anything into `initialise`.

Instead, you can make `B4` global, or you can remove it from the function.

**`global`**:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
global B4
top = Tkinter.Tk()
B1 = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="circle", relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="circle")
B2 = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="plus", relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="plus")
B3 = Tkinter.Button(top, text=u"good !",relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="plus")
def initialise(self):
    global B4
    self.grid()
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click me !",
                                command=OnButtonClick(self))
    B4.grid(column=1,row=0)
def OnButtonClick(self):
    print( "You clicked the button" )

initialise(top)
B1.pack()
B2.pack()
B3.pack()
B4.pack()
#initialise()
top.mainloop()
```

---

Runs as:

```
bash-3.2 $
You clicked the button
```

[image]

**Outside of function:**

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.grid()
def OnButtonClick(self):
    print( "You clicked the button" )
B1 = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="circle", relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="circle")
B2 = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="plus", relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="plus")
B3 = Tkinter.Button(top, text=u"good !",relief=RAISED,\
                         cursor="plus")
B4 = Tkinter.Button(top,text=u"Click me !",                                                              
                                command=OnButtonClick(top))
B4.grid(column=1,row=0)


B1.pack()
B2.pack()
B3.pack()
B4.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

---

Runs as:

```
bash-3.2 $
You clicked the button
```

[image]

---

Example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     bar = 6
... 
>>> bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: could you  help me to make it global and print,because i traced some examples and i dont know how to display B4

Comment: @user3705347 the first example has the code you need.

Comment: @user3705347 If this answer helped you do you mind accepting it by clicking on the green check next to my answer? Fill disclosure: it gives you +2 reputation :)

Comment: i clicked but it only display "click me" button not other buttons displays and gets some error.